# iOS Test Flight doesn't work properly?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I just started using test flight and I can't understand what's different between me getting the app in my iOS device through pressing PLAY on Xcode project and getting my app on iOS device through test flight. I'm using test flight now and NOTHING is different. I'm not receiving any reports from test flight of any kind about any issues either. I'm now the internal tester to my own app because I want to see how Test flight works. I don't understand how it works because I'm not receiving anything back from test flight to email, to test flight app, to iTunes Connect.  No data or bug reports. What's the point of test flight then?

Also, why does Test Flight show my app with a Release Date: May 30th, 2015? After the 29 days of testing, does it automatically release my app for review with App store?

Comment: Gotta read the docs, brother: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Flight is to distribute your app to beta testers. If you are in a corporate setting you could create a build and send it to your managers (Internal Testers) to review before submitting to the App Store. You could additionally set up a select number of your customers (External Testers) to test the update as well.

These people, being beta testers, would inform you of any bugs or issues they encountered while testing.

Comment: What about crash logs? On Xcode when I clicked submit to App Store I needed to click to include app symbols for my app to receive crash logs from Apple. So I did just that.  Then In Xcode I go to Windows --> Organizer, I don't see any crash logs. How do I find crash logs?

Comment: I'm not sure if that feature is available yet. I read that it was shared at the last WWDC but that the feature would be released in the next year so it may not be available yet.

Comment: No I just found it but good luck understanding what it states. Plug in your device, Window --> Devices --> View Device Logs. Click on the crash. Good luck understand what the crash is saying, I have no clue.